# One xib, many ViewControllers - is it a proper way?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xib, nib

I'm new to iOS. I'm currently developing an iOS application and I have a small question to you. I have few ViewControllers which Views are the same - a tableView with some data. Only the logic is different - if you select a row, different things happen, also the rows look a little bit different, but those differences are made in the ViewControllers code. My question is, what is the proper way for creating xibs for those ViewControllers? Should I create new xib for each ViewController or just one for all of them? If one, what with the FilesOwner of xib? I set it in xCode, so should I change it or what? Is it good to have only one View?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all views are `UITableView`s you would only need one xib file (lets name it GenericTableView.xib), add your `UITableView`, connect it with the file owner which is simply a `UITableViewController`. After that create separate subclasses of `UITableViewController` and implement your specific behavior in there.

In your code you can the easily initiate any of your `UITableViewController` subclasses with

```
[[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GenericTableView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is right, but I don't feel confortable instantiating ViewControllers or using xib in code. I let the segues do all the work.

I would have a base class, let's say GenericTableViewController and define common behavior there (like IBActions or interactions with the UI), the view is also inherited so all the subclasses (viewcontrollers) share it.

Comment: What if the project doesn't use a storyboard? Then you have to load the xibs yourself (that, or create the view controllers completely in code).

Comment: You can always add a storyboard, and adapt your project. No matter if you use XIB or storyboards, ViewControllers have to be written.

Answer (score 0):

`Swift 4.2`

```
MyViewController.init(nibName: "MyGenericVC", bundle: Bundle.main)
```